# automatic install software in windows with

Tags: windows, installation

I will need to do installation work for a few PCs with windows. The installation will require: 
- Check Java installation, version, if not installed or with older version, then install java latest version
- install Cygwin default, python and some other sw.

Is there any easy way to do so automatically with some kind of .exe file or script?

Comment: So your asking for a setup creation tool? http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php. For deployment in a domain environment you can use Group Policy.

Comment: Actually I need to setup a hadoop cluster with computers running windows, and Linux. Is there any good tool to easily setup many computers?

Comment: I found the solution is by using hadoop distributions instead of installing plain hadoop in my case